# How to take only the date out of columns and copy the date to another column with another format of the date?

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy, google-sheets-api

[image: example]

The script should take the date out of column B and only cope the date to D and format it to european date format.
Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to use a script for this. The `regexextract` function can extract the date, which can then be recombined into whatever format. It's best to use three helper columns, which may be hidden (say, X, Y, Z). In X2, put

```
=regexextract(B2, "(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})")
```

This will place the month, date, and year in cells X2, Y2, Z2. Then in D2, put

```
=Y2 & "." & X2 & "." & Z2
```

and you are done.

This also works in `arrayformula` mode, handling the entire column at once:

```
=iferror(arrayformula(regexextract(B2:B, "(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})")))
```

where `iferror` suppresses error from cells that don't contain a date.

After that,

```
=arrayformula(if(len(Z2:Z), Y2:Y & "." & X2:X & "." & Z2:Z, ))
```

recombines the date, again leaving blanks where no date was parsed out.